# How to fix "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to show ArrayList in RecycleView which wrap in the fragment, but when I run the apk, it didn't show up the RV. And when I saw on logcat, there's note "No Adapter Attached; skipping layout".

I tried so many ways to change on fragment, and adapter too, but that wasn't worked after all. Since the other questions on this site based on API, I don't understand, cause I'm a beginner. I tried to figure out a question which based on Arraylist, the result is still the same, none of that solution is based on my problem.

I'll show the code from my Adapter, fragment, and mainActivity, it'll long, but I want to know the problem cause I'm lost and clueless.

**Fragment:**

```
public class FilmFragment extends Fragment {


    View view;
    ArrayList<Film> list = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView rvCategory;
    FilmDatas filmDatas;


    public FilmFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie,container,false);
        return view;}
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rvCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCategory);
        rvCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list.addAll(filmDatas.getListData());
        showRecycleList();}
private void showRecycleList(){
        rvCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        FilmAdapter adapter = new FilmAdapter(getContext());
        adapter.setListMovie(list);
        rvCategory.setAdapter(adapter);}}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class FilmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilmAdapter.CategotyViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Film> listFilm;


    public ArrayList<Film> getList(){ 
        return listFilm; }

    public void setListMovie(ArrayList<Film> list) {
        this.listFilm = list;}

    public FilmAdapter(Context context
    ) {this.context = context;}


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategotyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_film,parent,false);
        return new CategotyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CategotyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Film film = listFilm.get(position);

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(film.getPhoto()).apply(new RequestOptions().override(100,100))
                .into(holder.imgPhoto);
        holder.tvName.setText(film.getName());
        holder.tvFrom.setText(film.getFrom());
        holder.tvDate.setText(film.getDate());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return getList().size();
    }

    public class CategotyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       ImageView imgPhoto;
       TextView tvName,tvFrom,tvDate;

        public CategotyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_from);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);}}
```

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.Frame);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpelTab);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    private class sliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String movie = "MOVIE";
        String tvShow = "TV SHOW";
        final String tabs[] = {movie, tvShow};

        public sliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new FilmFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new TvShowFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabs.length; //count Tabs[] size: 2
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    }
```

**FilmDatas :**

```
public class FilmDatas { public static String [][] data = new String[][]{
        {
                "Venom (2018)","Investigative journalist Eddie Brock attempts a comeback following a scandal, but accidentally becomes the host of Venom, a violent, super powerful alien symbiote. Soon, he must rely on his newfound powers to protect the world from a shadowy organization looking for a symbiote of their own.","https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_face/2uNW4WbgBXL25BAbXGLnLqX71Sw.jpg","https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w533_and_h300_bestv2/VuukZLgaCrho2Ar8Scl9HtV3yD.jpg","October 5, 2018"
        }

};
    public ArrayList<Film> getListData() {
        ArrayList<Film> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String[] aData : data) {
            Film film = new Film();
            film.setName(aData[0]);
            film.setFrom(aData[1]);
            film.setBackground(aData[2]);
            film.setPhoto(aData[3]);
            film.setDate(aData[4]);

            list.add(film);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Film : (it contains parcelable and set/get)**

```
public class Film implements Parcelable {
    private String name,from,background,photo,date;

    public Film() {

    }


    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName (String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getFrom() {return from;}
    public void setFrom (String from) {this.from = from;}
    public String getBackground() {return background;}
    public void setBackground (String background) {this.background = background;}
    public String getPhoto() {return photo;}
    public void setPhoto (String photo) {this.photo = photo;}
    public String getDate() {return date;}
    public void setDate (String date) {this.date = date;}

    protected Film(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        from = in.readString();
        background = in.readString();
        photo = in.readString();
        date = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Film> CREATOR = new Creator<Film>() {
        @Override
        public Film createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Film(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Film[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Film[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(from);
        parcel.writeString(background);
        parcel.writeString(photo);
        parcel.writeString(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: tip: you have globally declared private `FilmAdapter adapter;` but never used, instead you do the instance with the same name after `FilmAdapter adapter = new FilmAdapter(getContext());` , delete the first global declaration if you are gonna use it that way

Comment: @GastónSaillén i thought in case the solution will be need that, i didn't erase it. Because some solution i tried before used it, then this is (i forgot how many time i changed the code) the new one :)

Comment: it might cause confusion of which of the adapter is being used since they have the same name

Comment: @GastónSaillén ok, edited :)

Comment: The recyclerview is shown empty ? Does the app compiles ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén yup, it's compiles. not crash, etc, just got red in there. are you need the set/get and the ArrayList ? maybe there's problem in there.

Comment: @darkalam are you saying that everything is working, you just have the error in the log?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai no, the app didn't crash, but the datas didn't show up, and when i see at fragment, datas already declare, and the log show me that red

Comment: @darkalam where is your data coming from? I don't see any declared data.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai done, added the FilmDatas and Film :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relies at your Fragment.

You have declared

```
FilmDatas filmDatas;
```

But you never instantiated it, or even fill any object of it here

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rvCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCategory);
        rvCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list.addAll(filmDatas.getListData());
        showRecycleList();
}
```

So, there is no data to populate your list, and your recyclerview will not show anything

Try by adding elements to the list like this to test

```
list.add(new FilmDatas("param1","param2"...))
```

Also, you are declaring your list as type Film, but you are populating it with FilmDatas type

But I assume that `filmData.getListData()` returns the object of type Film that you want to populate.

The problem is not the  `“No adapter attached; skipping layout”` , the problem is that you are not adding any element to your list, and when you set the list to the adapter , it does not bind any of that data inside of each recyclerview row, and `getItemCount()` returns 0, and so your recyclerview does not show nothing.

Comment: so i check the arraylist, that's inform me the datas can't be static, so i deleted that and wrote like your solution, and the app got crash. here is : AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.example.apkfin2, PID: 18451
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.apkfin2.FilmDatas.getListData()' on a null object reference
FilmFragment.showRecycleList(FilmFragment.java:59) FilmFragment.onViewCreated(FilmFragment.java:53)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)

Comment: did you filled the data of the object like the one you have declared ? I put "param1","param2" as example, but there should be your constructor data

Comment: yes, filmDatas.getListData() is null because is never instantiated, also, the instantiation inside list.add(new FilmDatas...) is of type FilmDatas, and your List is of type Film, you should change the List with ArrayList <FilmDatas> ...

Comment: added FilmDatas and Film, maybe it help to know the problem

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your issue has to do with this code:

```
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rvCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCategory);
    rvCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list.addAll(filmDatas.getListData());
    showRecycleList();}

private void showRecycleList(){
        rvCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        FilmAdapter adapter = new FilmAdapter(getContext());
        adapter.setListMovie(list);
        rvCategory.setAdapter(adapter);}}
```

You are adding the list after the `RecyclerView` has been created without refreshing your view. You can handle this one of two ways: update your method to update the view with the data; or, pass in the data when you create the adapter.

If you wanted to just refresh the list, which is helpful for data that you might receive after the view is inflated (think of getting the data from an API request), then you just need to add `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

**Adapter:**

```
  public void setListMovie(ArrayList<Film> list) {
    this.listFilm = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Otherwise, you would just pass your data in when you create your adapter:

**Adapter:**

```
 public FilmAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Film> list) {
      this.context = context;
      this.listFilm = list;
 }
```

Then in your `Fragment` you would do something like:

```
 private void showRecycleList(){
    rvCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    if(list != null){
         FilmAdapter adapter = new FilmAdapter(getContext(), list);
         rvCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
         //Handle error
    }

  }
```

Comment: It's still didnt work,  i tried solution from Gaston too, but the resulted were no adapter attached, or error in list.addAll(filmDatas.getList()) ; i wondering, is that because getBackground didnt called in adapter, so in adapter only grab 4 datas, not 5 datas like in Arraylist

Comment: I would check the data that you are sending into the array. Did you try both options I suggested?

Comment: yup, there's my fault any way, it get red because i forgot to make adapter and fill it to another fragment. Then again i try , it help me with the red. when i try your solution, still the same, i don't know, i got the RV empty, then i tried to use bottomNav, instead Tablayout, it's work, all your code. i don't know why my mainActivity with Tablayout can't show the RV